# Screenlets not auto starting in lubuntu

Tags: 13.10, 14.04, lubuntu, autostart, screenlets

I am trying to auto start FolderView Screenlets in Lubuntu 13.10

There is plenty of advice on the web for ubuntu, with which i did not have any issues.

I got the screenlets manager to autostart after adding "screenlets" to autostart in lxsession-default-apps, however the FolderView's does not autostart.

Also in the Screenlets Manager under options i have selected Auto Start on login.

I'm going to install 14.04 on another machine to test if that will not work better.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've tested it on Lubuntu 14.04 with no problems. What are the content of your `$HOME/.config/autostart` folder?

Comment: Thanx for the hope. FolderViewScreenlet.desktop Screenlets Daemon.desktop

Comment: Ok the content is right must be a other problem. Try it on 14.04 should be the best.

Comment: Got the problem. Went to preferences, Default applications for LXSession, Autostart. Under Settings, Changed "Disable autostarted applications?" to No. It was set to config-only. Thank you for the help!